# Let $f$ be absolutely continuous on $[0,a]$ for all $a>0$ and $f(0)=0$ the show that $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)f'(t)|\leq\frac{1}{2}(\int_{0}^{x}|f'(t)|)^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be absolutely continuous on $[0,a]$ for all $a>0$ and $f(0)=0$ the show that $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)f'(t)|\leq\frac{1}{2}(\int_{0}^{x}|f'(t)|)^2$.

How I did it:

Clear for $x=0$. Now we take the derivative of both sides noting that indefinite integrals are absolutely continuous. Thus we get $|f(x)f'(x)|\leq|f'(x)|\int_{0}^{x}|f'(x)| \iff |f(x)|\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f'(x)|$ But the last inequality is true as $|f(x)|\leq TVf[0,x]$.

Is this correct? IS there a different way to justify $|f(x)|\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f'(x)|$  than they way I did?

Comment: You could justify it as follows: since $f$ is absolutely continuous and $f(0)=0$, $f=\int_0^x f'(t)dt$. Applying the modulus $|f|=\left|\int_0^x f'(t)dt\right|\le \int_0^x |f'(t)|dt$

Comment: @Caffeine I was wondering where is the $f(0)=0$ going to be useful. Thank you!

Comment: the $f(0)=0$ is used also in $|f(x)|\le TVf[0,x]$

Comment: @Caffeine That does not pose a problem to my solution though, right? All I want to show is that the left hand side grrows faster or the same speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but it overlooks a passage: the inequality $|f(x)|\le TVf[0,x]$ is not true in general, where we instead have $|f(x)|\le TVf[0,x]+|f(0)|$. However, since $|f(0)|=0$ by hypotesis, the particular inequality is valid and we are done.

Another derivation of $|f(x)|\le \int |f'(x)dx$ is
by the second fundamental theorem of calculus, 
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)dt\\
|f(x)|=\left|\int_0^x f(t)dt\right|\le\int_0^x|f(t)|dt\\$$

Comment: Going back to this problem I now have some doubts about the solution. Afterall, the derivative might exist a.e and so we cannot conclude anything like we did.

Comment: @2132123 changing the integrand on a set of measure $0$ does not change the integral. Thanks to this we can define $f'=0$ where it is not defined, and the conclusion follows

Comment: Another way to avoid this problem is to note that, if $g'$ is integrable and $≥0$ a.e. then $g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^bg'(t)dt\ge \frac{1}{n}\mu\{g'(t)\ge n\}\ge 0$ (by Chebychev inequality). Thus, even if you prove that a derivative is non-negative a.e., this is enough to imply monotonicity, given that $g'$ is integrable

Comment: Regarding your first response. I meant that $\int_{0}^{x}f'(x)$ is differentiable a.e as $f'$ is not necessarily continuous. Now if $f(0)<g(0)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ a.e we cannot conclude (so easily) that $f(x)<g(x)$ . Afterall the cantor function has derivative 0 a.e yet it grows faster (overall on $[0,1]$) than some linear functions.

Comment: I think the second comment has clear things up for me. We have two monotonic functions $g(x),f(x)$ s.t $f(0)=g(0)=0$ we also have that $0\leq g'(x)-f'(x)$ a.e . Now since they are both monotonic we take the integral of both sides to get $0\leq g(x)-f(x)$ by property of monotonic functions. I think that does it. Thank you very much !